# I have three text fields, want to choose between first two of them, & work with third one

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I have three text fields. I want to choose between first two of them, & work with third one.

How to do it? Please guide

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new CalculatorApp());

class CalculatorApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title:'Bending Calculator',
      home: Calculator()
    );
  }
}

class Calculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Calculatore();
}

class Calculatore extends State<Calculator> {
final a = TextEditingController();
  final b = TextEditingController();
  final c = TextEditingController();
// controller mentioned
 String total= "";

void calculate()  {
    int numberA = int.parse(a.text);
    int numberB = int.parse(b.text);
    int numberC = int.parse(c.text);
    int  result;
// if numberA have value then answer will be a+c


if( 
// what condition to do here for between choosing between  textfields a or b.
// i tried numberB ==null   that does not work
// very much confused, no idea what to do please help

){
result = numberA + numberC
} else{ result = numberB + numberC
}


    setState(() {
      total = "$result";
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title:Text("Calculator")),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // first textfield

                    Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.45 ,height: 50,
                       child: TextField(
                           controller: a,
                           decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: " Enter a value"),
                           keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
                    ),
                    Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,height: 50,),
                    // second textfield
                    Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.45,height: 50,
                      child: TextField(
                          controller: b,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: " Enter  b value"),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number),), ],
                ),
               
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    // third textfield

                    Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.9, height: 50,
                      child: TextField(
                          controller: c,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "   Enter c value"),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number),),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    //button

                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: calculate,
                      child: Text('Calculate'),),
                  ],
                ),
                Text("   Total : $total", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
      ],
            ))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share image of what you want to achieve & current result

Comment: Please format the code properly and add more description as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: i do not get answer until i fill all three textfields, after fill all three textfields then i get the answer. but i want answer with 1st +3rd textfields or 2nd + 3rd textfields with pout filling all textfields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment this should perhaps help. A normal `int.parse` will throw error if the text you provide to parse is empty. Instead use `int.tryParse` as in the documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/int/tryParse.html). This will return a `null` if the provided string is empty. Live version available in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9f7f87cb8e15fe1385c017d5fb884858).

```
    int numberA = int.tryParse(a.text);
    int numberB = int.tryParse(b.text);
    int numberC = int.tryParse(c.text);
    int result;

    // if numberA have value then answer will be a+c

    // Note following conditions have order precedence. So only one of them execute.     
    if (numberA != null && numberC != null) {
      result = numberA + numberC;
    } else if (numberB != null && numberC != null){
      result = numberB + numberC;
    }
```

If you want to calculate the totat if all three fields are present. Use the following condition.

```dart
    if (numberA != null && numberB != null && numberC != null) {
      result = numberA + numberB + numberC;
    } else if (numberA != null && numberC != null) {
      result = numberA + numberC;
    } else if (numberB != null && numberC != null){
      result = numberB + numberC;
    }
```

You can achieve the same by checking the text instead of parsed number.

Comment: thank you for answer  it works very well, thanks for your valuable time too :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have tried checking whether the value of text field b is null. Have you tried to check whether `b.text.isEmpty` or `isNotEmpty`.

Comment: thanks @user1278588 if (b.text.isEmpty) {
      result = numberA + numberC ;
    } else {
      result = numberB + numberC;}

    setState(() {
      total = "$result";
    });
  }

Comment: now this works,  thank you  for your valuable time  :)

Answer (score 0):

"" can't parse to int.
You can use "try & catch" or "tryParese".
How about this?

```
void calculate() {
  int numberA = int.tryParse(a.text);
  int numberB = int.tryParse(b.text);
  int numberC = int.tryParse(c.text);
  int result;

  if (numberB == null) {
    result = numberA + numberC;
  } else {
    result = numberB + numberC;
  }

  setState(() {
    total = "$result";
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer ( try & catch ),  it works very well, thanks for your valuable time too :)